# how to interval call with parameter angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

how to $interval call function with parameter

```
$interval( getrecordeverytime(2), 100000);
 function getrecordeverytime(contactId)
        {
          console.log(contactId + 'timer running');
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters starting from fifth argument of `$interval`:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $interval){
  function getrecordeverytime(contactId, second) {
      console.log(`${contactId}, ${second} timer running`);
  };
  $interval(getrecordeverytime, 1000, 0, true, 2, 5);
})
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
        function getrecordeverytime(contactId){
          console.log(contactId + 'timer running');
        }    
        $interval(function(){getrecordeverytime(2)},100000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create a function that returns the interval callback function, and have the parameter bound to the callback through closure. Like this:

```
function createRecordCallback(contactId){
    return function(){
        console.log(contactId + 'timer running'); // the value of contactId, will be bound to this function.
    };
}

$interval(createRecordCallback(1234), 100000);
```

This is merely meant as an alternative. I do recommend Slava's answer in most cases.